# Django view not passing all variables to template, only some

Tags: python, html, django

I am greatly puzzled by this one, any light on the subject would be appreciated.

I have view code thusly:

```
@login_required
def product(request, prod_id):                                                                              
    prod = Product.objects.get(pk=prod_id)                                                    
    page_title = "Company Name - " + prod.item_name
    itm_name = Unescaped_HTML(prod.item_name)                                                            
    itm_num = prod.item_num                                                                          
    ret_price = prod.retail_price                                                                           
    front_img = prod.front_image                                                                         
    back_img = prod.back_image
    flap_img = prod.flap_image                                                                                        
    prd_type = prod.product_type[0].upper()
    tax_1 = prod.tax_ca                                                                                             
    tax_2 = prod.tax_co                                                                   
    pic1_img = prod.pic1_image                                                            
    pic2_img = prod.pic2_image                                                            
    pic3_img = prod.pic3_image                                                            
    pic4_img = prod.pic4_image                                                            
    urlpath = request.get_full_path()                                                     
    return render_to_response(                                                            
            "rgwebprodbase/productpage.html",                                             
            locals(),                                                                     
            context_instance = RequestContext(request)                                    
            )
```

A small portion of the template code (abbreviated in some places):

```
<form id="cart_form" action="https://www.website.com/qs3/cart.php" method="POST" target="cartFrame" />
    <Select NAME="item-{{ itm_num }}|{{ ret_price }}|{{ itm_name }}|{{ prd_type }}|{{ tax_1 }},{{ tax_2 }}" VALUE="1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <input name="store_type" type="hidden" value="html" />
    <input id="add_button" type="image" name="add_to_cart" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/cart/addtocart.jpg" alt="Add to Cart Button" />
    <input name="page" type="hidden" value="{{ urlpath }}" /> | 
        <a href="https://www.website.com/qs3/cart.php?view_cart=yes&amp;store_type=html&amp;page={{ urlpath }}">
            <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/cart/viewcart.jpg" alt="View Cart button" />
        </a> |
    <img id="close_button" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/forms/closewindow.jpg" alt="Close Form button" />
```

No matter what order I put the variables in, or whether I build a dictionary manually instead of using the locals() call, only some of the values are getting passed through to the template, and hence rendered correctly.  Specifically, all of the fields are showing up except prd_type, tax_1, tax_2, and urlpath.  I can verify that data is in the database to be pulled, I can even hard code some values in the View as literals (like 0.0725 for one of the tax fields).

Of note, all of the fields that are not showing up are the most recent changes made.  It seems as though my View code is frozen...

Any ideas?  Should I be bringing this to my host's attention?

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Comment: Your form is posting to a `.php` page? Are they both using the same database?

Comment: Hey Arun - Thanks for your Django tutorials!  And, to answer your question, although we are still using the php shopping cart, they do not (yet) share the same database.  That is for a future version/project.

Comment: You are welcome :) One possible cause could be that you are looking at the wrong database. Or use {% debug %} tag to print all the context variables.

Comment: Wow, I have never used that tag, what a large wall of text!  I see many of the variables listed alphabetically, precisely skipping the new variables... I even switched the code to specifically build a dictionary manually (instead of using locals()) to see if that would reduce all of the other clutter (like the Languages dictionary, MySQL stuff, WSGI stuff, etc.).  No joy...  But I did just realize that I have not run syncdb since I added the new fields, I manually changed the MySQL db - Maybe that is it... Time for another test!

Comment: No, syncdb did not resolve anything.  The SQL looks correct (SQLALL for the app specified) and it passes validation...  But I will now go and get the record from a dbshell to make sure the values are coming through.  Although an earlier test of replacing several of the missing fields with literals did not help, so this will not be the reason why they are not showing up in the template.  Sigh.

Comment: And to be clear, the Django code does not normally log into the PHP database, different MySQL db, different credentials.  I do have one function in Django that logs into the PHP database to do a specific field lookup, but I carefully close the connection when the function finishes...

Comment: Arun, thanks for your time.  I am feeling a bit foolish.  Wrong View code...

Comment: That's fine @Raintree most puzzling bug hunts end in an anti-climax :)

Comment: There is no reason to be passing all these variables at all. Most of them are simply attributes of the prod instance, so you should simply pass that and use the dot notation in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Um, oops.  Today's lesson: Make sure that one is editing the CORRECT view function.

My error was in thinking I was working on the view code for this URL, and in reality, it was being called by a different function.

Modifying the correct function is having the desired effect.

Thanks everyone...

And thanks to arocks I now have another tool in my arsenal: The {% debug %} template tag!

Comment: Your second error is the use of `locals()`. Don't worry, it will come and bite you in the end :)

Comment: Thanks, I read part of that debate, and decided I fall into the "lazy, takes shortcuts that are more pythonic" camp - Or like to fool myself into thinking that :)

Comment: I don't think `locals()` is more pythonic. Explicit is better than implicit; and I would be hard pressed to find a more "implicit" function than `locals()` or its other cousin `globals()`